# Изучение ООП в Python

Tags: python, ооп

Друзья, подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего лучше начать изучать ООП в Python-e.

Comment: Вообще-то довольно странный вопрос. Более простые: с чего начинать изучение Питона, с чего начинать изучение ООП. А данный вопрос несколько непонятен.

Comment: Большая часть ссылок уже не работает, а упоминаемые книги уже есть в "Книгах и учебных ресурсах по Python".

Answer (score 5):

Я начинал с Марка Лутца(4-е издание)...не скажу что много узнал,(много в этой книге упущено, несмотря на ее объем в 1200 страниц), хотя многому с него научился, пока всего 2 месяца изучаю питон..

Comment: Лутц очень размыто излагает, ИМХО, лучше книга М. Саммерфилда по 3-му Python

Answer (score 3):

С Главы III TaPL.

Comment: не надо сквернословить... :)

Answer (score 3):

Заглянуть в вики.

- [Python Programming/Object-oriented programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Object-oriented_programming)
- [Объектно-ориентированное программирование на Питоне](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5)

Answer (score 3):

Вот вам боянистый [блогопост](http://iproc.ru/2009/08/python-girls-oop/#post-3035). Прочитаете с удовольствием и сразу поймете ООП - Python, блэкджек и... ну вы поняли:)

Answer (score 2):

[David M. Beazley "Python подробный справочник"](http://vk.com/doc87353462_3746064?dl=d44d921b7fc1626d6c)

Answer (score 2):

[Абстрактные классы и интерфейсы](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/python/72757/)

Answer (score 2):

По-моему любой язык программирования требует практики и все они очень похожи! Я бы посоветовал просто начать писать....вы пишите программу, а язык это дело второе! Начните с очередного "Hello World" и неплохие примеры: решение квадратных уравнений, стрельба из пушки. Со справочникам по функциям всё будет успешно

Comment: Все они чем-то похожи и все они чем-то разные. Но вот изучение декларативных языков после изучения императивных (а ещё хуже -- после опыта работы) -- может стать проблемой. Правда тема -- ООП, так что упоминать декларативные не совсем уместно.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте почитать Пилгрима (Mark Pilgrim) Dive into Python. У него там отличные примеры разбираются, да и книжка в целом замечательная.